# Android studio app inspection can't open offline database

Tags: android, android-studio

The Android studio inspection shows an error message as below when I try to export the selected database file.

```
Issue while downloading database (word-card): Can't open offline database
 `/data/data/com.maxim.wordcard.debug/databases/word-card`
```

Comment: Did you check to see if that 'address' is working?  ie dir/w 'address' or similar.

Comment: @cliff2310 I am not sure what you mean exactly, however, thanks for your keen help anyway. I have found a solution and posted it below.

Comment: What I meant was you should try to verify the address was correct.  Usually by some other method.  Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug from Android Studio, I have resolved it by replacing it with [Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 RC 1 August 16, 2022](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Comment: I have latest first of Android Studio still same error is coming

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue while exporting data, been having it since I started working with Android Studio 6 months ago, still have it now in Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2. On emulator as well as physical device.

I circumvented the problem by downloading the database file from the **Device Explorer**, and opening it with an SQLite browser (SQLiteStudio.app in my case).