# Request for Assistance: Database Access Issue on Emulated Device

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am reaching out regarding an issue that I have encountered in my development process. When attempting to open the local database /data/data/com.example.handwritingfontconverter/databases/SettingsDB, I receive the following error:

```
Can't open offline database `/data/data/com.example.handwritingfontconverter/databases/SettingsDB`: Device 'Pixel_XL_API_28 emulator-5554' not found.
```

I seek your assistance in understanding and resolving this issue. There might be internal problems or conflicts that you can help address. I am prepared to provide additional data, logs, or any other information to facilitate the resolution of this situation.

My emulated Pixel XL API 28 system with the specified name 'emulator-5554' is connected and fully loaded. I have confirmed this using the adb devices command and also tracked the connection to the process with the identifier 6816.

Comment: Duplicate? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028822/android-studio-app-inspection-cant-open-offline-database